# for loop with fetchall_arrayref adding to an array

Tags: perl

How can I loop through my arrayref and push row data into an array I have?

Here is my code that does it once without a loop but what I want is it to do it for each row and not sure the best approach:

```
 my $data2 = $sth->fetchall_arrayref({});
 my $excludeFirstName = $data2 ->[0]->{EXCL_FRSTNAME};
 my $excludeLastName = $data2 ->[0]->{EXCL_LASTNAME};

    my @excluded;

    push (@excluded, $excludeFirstName." ".$excludeLastName);
```

Comment: It sounds like, in an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) sort of way, you're really trying to fetch the concatenation of two database columns (`EXCL_FRSTNAME` and `EXCL_LASTNAME`). If that's the case, it would be more efficient to change your SQL query to return the concatenation as a single column and only fetch that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my @excluded;
for my $row (@$data2) {
   push @excluded, "$row->{EXCL_FRSTNAME} $row->{EXCL_LASTNAME}";
}
```

Or

```
my @excluded = map { "$row->{EXCL_FRSTNAME} $row->{EXCL_LASTNAME}" } @$data2;
```

---

If you don't need `$data2` for anything else,

```
my @excluded;
while (my $row = $sth->fetch_hashref()) {
   push @excluded, "$row->{EXCL_FRSTNAME} $row->{EXCL_LASTNAME}";
}
```

Or

```
my $sql = 'SELECT CONCAT(EXCL_FRSTNAME, EXCL_LASTNAME) FROM ...';
my $excluded = $dbh->selectcol_arrayref($sql);
```